# Cannot load data to the UITableView from Firestore database collection

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firestore database and Swift.
I have collection of users and general collection of tasks. Each user has his own collection of tasks. When user sign up, I copy tasks from general collection of tasks to user's own collection of tasks.

My Firestore database hierarchy looks like this:
tasks -> firstBundle -> tasks
users -> userID -> tasks

Everything works to this moment. Then I want to load data from user's collection of tasks to the UITableView. When I manually add tasks to the user's collection of tasks, the data is displayed in the tableview. But when I copy data from general collection of tasks to the user's collection of tasks, the data isn't displayed in the tableview at all.

```
  class TasksListScreen: UIViewController {

    var db = Firestore.firestore()
    var tasksArray = [Task]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addTasks()
        loadData()
    }
```

Manually add data to the user's tasks collection and it works (the data is added to the database and tasks data is displayed in the tableview):

```
    // push tasks to the db
    func addTasks() {

        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let userTasksCollRef = db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("tasks")

        userTasksCollRef.addDocument(data: [
            "title": "Копійка гривню береже",
            "description": "Копійка гривню береже, чули таке? Чи є у Вас скарбничка? Якщо немає - є ідея. Спробуйте створити скарбничку своїми руками. Яка вона буде - справа Ваша. І ще, порада, заповніть ії.",
            "tip": "Живеться, якщо копійка ведеться",
            "hashtags": "#гроші #збереження #своїми руками"
        ])

        userTasksCollRef.addDocument(data: [
            "title": "В здоровому тілі - здоровий дух",
            "description": "Зробіть ранкову зарядку або пробіжку на свіжому повітрі.",
            "tip": "Фізична активність значно покращує самопочуття на цілий день",
            "hashtags": "#розвиток #фізична активність #здоров'я"
        ])
     }
```

Copy the data from the general collection of tasks (that was filled before manually on the database side) to user's collection of tasks and add copied data to the tableview.
The data is copied and it appears in the user's tasks collection in the Firestore database, but it is not loaded to the tableview.

```
    // push tasks to the db
    func addTasks() {

        // copy from db.collection("tasks").document("firstBundle").collection("tasks") = tasksFirstBundleCollRef
        // to db.collection("users").document(userID) = userRef

        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let userRef = db.collection("users").document(userID)
        let tasksFirstBundleCollRef = db.collection("tasks").document("firstBundle").collection("tasks")

        tasksFirstBundleCollRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
                    for document in snapshot.documents {
                        let data = document.data()
                        let batch = self.db.batch()
                        let docset = querySnapshot

                        let newCollRef = userRef.collection("tasks").document()

                        docset?.documents.forEach {_ in batch.setData(data, forDocument: newCollRef)}

                        batch.commit(completion: { (error) in
                            if let error = error {
                                print(error.localizedDescription)
                            } else {
                                print("Successfully copied doc")
                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And here is my method to load data from the database to the tableview:

```
    // load data to the table view from the db
    func loadData() {
        let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let userTasksCollRef = db.collection("users").document(userID).collection("tasks")

        userTasksCollRef.getDocuments { (queryShapshot, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading data: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            } else {
                self.tasksArray = queryShapshot!.documents.compactMap({Task(dictionary: $0.data())})
                print("Data: \(self.tasksArray)") 
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My Task file:

```
protocol DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary:[String:Any])
}

struct Task {
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var tip: String
    var hashtags: String

    var dictionary:[String:Any] {
        return [
            "title": title,
            "description": description,
            "tip": tip,
            "hashtags": hashtags
        ]
    }
}

extension Task : DocumentSerializable {
    init?(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        guard let title = dictionary["title"] as? String,
            let description = dictionary["description"] as? String,
            let tip = dictionary["tip"] as? String,
            let hashtags = dictionary["hashtags"] as? String else {return nil}

        self.init(title: title, description: description, tip: tip, hashtags: hashtags)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your task file:

```
class func parseData(snapshot: QuerySnapshot?) -> [Post] {
    var tasks = [Task]()

    guard let snap = snapshot else { return posts }
    for document in snap.documents {
        let data = document.data()
        let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
        let description = data["description"] as? String ?? ""
        let tip = data["tip"] as? [String] as? String ?? ""
        let hashtags = data["hashtags"] as? String ?? ""

        let task = Task(title: title, description: description, tip: tip, hashtags: hashtags)
        tasks.append(task)
    }

    return tasks
}
```

Then try to load the table with the following:

```
userTasksCollRef.getDocuments { (sapshot, error) in
    guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
       print("Error retrieving documents: \(error.debugDescription)")
       return
    }
    let task = Task.parseData(snapshot: snapshot)
    for task in tasks {
       self.tasksArray.append(task)
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```